# Read multiple .txt files in R with scan()

Tags: r, text

I have a corpus divided into many different .txt files from here: http://www.thegrammarlab.com/?nor-portfolio=corpus-of-presidential-speeches-cops-and-a-clintontrump-corpus

These data files are raw, and so I use the `scan` function like the following:

```
scan("Clinton_2016-07-28.txt", what = "character", sep=NULL)
```

I want to know how I can automate this to scan every file in the folder.
Also, I use `scan` because it creates a character vector which is what i am looking for.

Comment: Just `list.files()` to get a list of file names, then pass that into `scan` via `lapply` or `Map` or `purrr::map` (whatever your favorite mapping function is). It probably depends on what you are going to do with it afterward to know what might be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MrFlick mentioned you can use `list.files` to get all the text files in working directory and then you can use `lapply` to read them in a list.

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = '\\.txt$')
result <- lapply(filenames, scan, what = "character", sep=NULL)
```